# Get a field that have a not direct cardinality in yii2 model

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have a relation of a lot table like this
[image: relation]

How to get a field that have a not direct cardinality.
In my case in model deal_komisi like this :

```
class DealKomisi extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName() {
    return 'deal_komisi';
}

//relation between deal_komisi and list harga :
public function getListHarga() {
    return $this->hasOne(ListHarga::className(), ['id' => 'list_harga_id']);
}

}
```

As you can see, between deal komisi to list harga is looked like above.
My question is, it possible to :

1. related **deal komisi table** to **item_layanan table**
2. which is **list_harga table** to **item_layanan_table** is related by **list_harga.item_layanan_id** = **item_layanan.id**
3. I need to get item_layanan.nama item

Please advice, thanks

**Update**
This is my ListHargaModel :

```
class ListHarga extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'list_harga';
}

public function getItemLayanan()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ItemLayanan::className(), ['id' => 'item_layanan_id']);
 }
 }
```

Comment: show `ListHarga` model.

Comment: See my update question

Comment: Try `DealKomisi->listHarga->itemLayanan->nama_item`